# how to display multiple images from sql server to multiple picturebox at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display the picture result from my database inside the picture box on my form but I just don't know how to go about it. this is the code I have, please what change can I make to this code to achieve this.. thanks in advance

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection

            cn = New SqlConnection
            cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ALLAYE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-commerce;Integrated Security=True"

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("use [E-commerce];SELECT ProductTB.ProductImage  FROM ProductTB WHERE ProductID = 'shoe1'")
        cn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = cn

            Dim ImgStream As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte()))
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            ProductImagePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ImgStream)

            ImgStream.Dispose()

            cmd.Connection.Close()
```

my question is how can i update this code to be able to display multiple images into my picture box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested elsewhere:

```
'Clear any existing images if required.
For Each pictureBox In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Cast(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
    pictureBox.Image.Dispose()
    pictureBox.Dispose()
Next

Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ALLAYE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-commerce;Integrated Security=True"),
      command As New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductImage FROM ProductTB", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Do While reader.Read()
            Using stream As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(reader("ProductImage"), Byte()))
                Dim img = Image.FromStream(stream)
                Dim pictureBox As New PictureBox With {.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize,
                                                       .Image = img}

                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox)
            End Using
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

That assumes that you have added a `FlowLayoutPanel` control to your form named `FlowLayoutPanel1`.  That control will allow you to add and remove controls at run-time and it will handle the layout automatically.

The code above also cleans up some of the things you were already doing, like removing unnecessary parts from your SQL code and adding `Using` statements.  It removes your `WHERE` clause and thus gets every record in the table.  You can change that to just get some records if you want.  The data reader will read each one in turn and add it to the form in a new `PictureBox`.

Comment: Thanks man, the code works but only one image is been display on the flow layout, how can I go about that

Comment: If the `FlowLayoutPanel` only shows one `PictureBox` then only one `PictureBox` is being added, which means that only one record is being read.  Before posting anything here, you need to debug your code. That means setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line to see what it does. If you do that and you see only a single record being read then asking why only a single `PictureBox` is displayed would be a silly question. You know there's only one record and, if that's not what you expect, you need to then work out why that is. Most likely, there's only one record to read.